# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toJSON') and one more

Tags: javascript

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.commands = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});
```

client.login(token);

```
that's the index.js file 


the error= TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shado\OneDrive\Pulpit\Command\index.js:12:35)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47





there is also a second issue


TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toJSON')
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shado\OneDrive\Pulpit\Command\deploy-commands.js:11:29)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47




    const fs = require('fs');
    const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
    const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
    const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');
    
    const commands = [];
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
        commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
    }
    
    const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);
    
    rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: commands })
        .then(() => console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
        .catch(console.error);
```

^ deploy-commands.js
the second issue concerns that

i have no idea what is happening, it worked yesterday, everything is falling apart, please help

there have been no major changes made since it last worked on my pc. none at all to the code of these two files themselves, only additional commands being added

Comment: Can you show the output from `command.data`??

Comment: i will not lie, i am completely new to this and do not understand a thing, sorry for being difficult but i really wanna learn this stuff, so that's to say i have no idea where to find command.data

Comment: Okey. 12 line of your code `command.data.name`. Try with `console.log(command.data)` and let me know

Comment: Also will be nice if you explain what are you trying to achieve. It will be more easy to figure out the answer.

Comment: well it was workning before, i'm trying to restore it to working condition, if you're asking what the discord bot will do, it will just do simple replies to / commands

Comment: console.log(command.data) just brings up the names and descriptions of each individual command i already coded

Comment: The function brings up objects?

Comment: Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\shado\OneDrive\Pulpit\Command> node .
K {
  options: [
    z {
      name: 'target',
      description: "The user's avatar to show",
      required: false,
      type: 6
    }
  ],
  name: 'avatar',
  description: 'Get a good look at a pfp.',
  defaultPermission: undefined
}

Comment: that, two more commands that didn't fit in the character limit and the error described in the post

Comment: As I see from the documentation, `toJSON()` is used by `JSON.stringify` that requires a well formed object for work. Your `command.data` type is an `Object`? I can not see it clearly

Comment: how do i check that again?

Comment: This seems malfromed object `{options: [z {name:...]` it must have two dots before the bracket `z:{name:...}`.

Comment: i looked around online and couldn't find much of a way to check, but if i had to guess, it isn't an object, but that's just a guess

Comment: It will be more easy if you copy the output of `console.log(command.data)` to your comment, remember to add `### Update`

Comment: You can check the type of a variable using typeof(var). In your case `console.log(typeof(command.data))`

Comment: Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\shado\OneDrive\Pulpit\Command> node .
C:\Users\shado\OneDrive\Pulpit\Command\index.js:12
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
 ### Update

Comment: does this anyhow help?

Comment: I am refereed to the StackOverFlow comment.

Comment: i used console.log(typeof(command.data)) and it didn't say anything new actually

Comment: What it return?

Comment: exact same thing as before

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try printing both command and command.data and look at the types. For me when i did typeof(command.data) i saw that one of my objects was undefined. This was due to a typo in my user.js file in commands folder. Instead of data i had written Data.